# Json deserialization issue in xamarin forms

Tags: json, xamarin.forms, deserialization

I have a xamarin.forms application in which I am deserialize a json data. Deserialization worked fine until an extra double quotes appeared on the json.The json deserializer throwed an error.

**My Json data**

```
 {
  "Model_id": 403,
  "Model": "iPad Pro 9.7""
}
```

The extra " after 9.7 causes the problem. But that double quotes indicates the inches of the device.

**My deserialization**

```
 resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultJSON);
```

How Can I solve this? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply speaking, the presented JSON is not a valid JSON. See the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7):

> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C
> family of programming languages.  A string begins and ends with
> quotation marks.  All Unicode characters may be placed within the
> quotation marks, **except for the characters that must be escaped:
> quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters** (U+0000
> through U+001F).

(Emphasis mine)

This means, that you have to escape the quotation mark within the string.

```
{
  "Model_id": 403,
  "Model": "iPad Pro 9.7\""
}
```

**Strictly speaking** the preferred way of escaping characters is by their unicode escape sequence, i.e. a backslash followed by an `u` and then the unicode number, which would be \u0022 for a quotation mark. This would render your JSON

```
{
  "Model_id": 403,
  "Model": "iPad Pro 9.7\u0022"
}
```

*Anyway*, the RFC also states

> Alternatively, there are two-character sequence escape
> representations of some popular characters.

and `\"` is one of them.

Comment: Bro how can I escape the quotation mark within the string?

Comment: @AndroDevil Sry, I do not understand your question. I showed in my answer, how to escape the quotation mark.

Comment: If you read the JSON from a file, you'll have to fix that file, if it comes from a web service, you'll have to fix that web service.

Comment: Ok bro I Understood.